# Session locked after xubuntu-desktop installing

Tags: suspend, xfce, session

After the installing `xubuntu-desktop` i've removed it. Now when my PC go to sleep mode and wake up then i see standard ubuntu login window. Ok. I write my password and i see black screen with randomly placed text. Then, after few seconds, i again see login window, but now session is dead so when i log in all soft is closed. It is not good. Also, if i press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and Ctrl+Alt+F7 before entering password, i see `XFCE`'s message "Session locked". What i did to solve that problem:

```
# apt-get purge xfce*
# apt-get remove lightdm ubuntu-desktop unity
# apt-get install lightdm ubuntu-desktop unity
```

Didn't helped. Here is /var/log/pm-suspend.log

```
Thu Dec 25 15:32:50 EET 2014: performing suspend Thu Dec 25 15:32:56 EET 2014: Awake. Thu Dec 25 15:32:56 EET 2014: Running hooks for resume Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: not executable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: Reloaded unloaded modules. /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null) error: No such file or directory /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: not executable.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01laptop-mode resume suspend: Laptop mode enabled, not active sh: echo: I/O error SETTING OF KERNEL PARAMETER FAILED: echo ondemand \> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor sh: echo: I/O error SETTING OF KERNEL PARAMETER FAILED: echo ondemand \> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01laptop-mode resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: Error for wireless request «Set Power Management» (8B2C) : SET failed on device mon0 ; Invalid argument. Failed. Error for wireless request «Set Power Management» (8B2C) : SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument. Failed. /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.

Thu Dec 25 15:32:57 EET 2014: Finished.
```

Help me please! Thanks.

Comment: you should be using sudo!

Comment: i did it as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case following helps:

```
sudo apt-get purge light-locker
```

Comment: But then, what will handle locking the screen? Am I missing something?